# POST JSON Request to a RESTful service + server deployment

Tags: c#, json, rest, post, deployment

I'm looking to make a web service to be available in the form
of ASP.NET MVC routing, meaning "base_url/controller/action",
optionally with some extra parameters for GET requests, plus
some other "actions" for POST requests.

I would like to first test them locally, on "localhost",
then if everything's OK to deploy them onto a remote
server and then test remotely, in the interest of
eventually publishing that web service to my customers.

Using "VS Express 2012 for Web", and also the equivalent
edition "VS Express 2012 for Desktop", I've been able
to make an "ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application" with
a "Web API" template, and also a client console application
to send POST requests with, for QA purposes.

The "Web Service" project has been partially created in accordance
with a Youtube video of "REST API in ASP.NET MVC", by Michael Crosby,
available at "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agImzri6X64", where
he presents a pretty good way on how to do both consuming AND returning
of JSON, however at some points he refers the viewers to some external library which unfortunately didn't compile.

The "Web Service" project itself seemed to have tested OK locally,
both for GET and POST requests, however when tested remotely
on a cloud-based server, the POST request returned a 404 error.

The "POST request maker" console application has been borrowed "as is"
from MSDN, at "msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx",
and seemed to have tested OK on both "localhost" for GET and POST requests
but NOT so well remotely.

My questions are :

1) What would be the absolutely minimum set of steps required to make
   a C# web service allowing both GET and POST of JSON strings ?

2) What files would I have to deploy on a remote server (IIS 10 I think)
   preferably without the ".cs" source files, in order to make
   that web service available online ?
- What I've previously attempted was a simple ZIP and UnZip of all
   of the project files into "C:\inetpub\wwwroot", and it did return
   the "View" for the template's homepage correctly.

3) Are there any extra configurations to be made on either
   the web service project's files or the server's IIS panel ?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance
Me, a puzzled developer...

Comment: How did you deploy the web service to remote server? Are you able to access the service domain over internet? Where did you deploy the web service? Azure, AWS, your own server, some other hosting environment, which one?

Comment: Hi,

I deployed it on AWS where we have a Free Tier account.
A previously-deployed WebForms-style website had worked
perfectly well, so I guess that means that it is entirely possible
to access the AWS-assigned URL over the Internet with ease.